# angular material2 select component alignment

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using a material components and I want to know if is possible to set the size of dropdown select to be exactly with the size of mat-form-field.

the default component is like:

[image]

And I want to modify that in order to have the dropdown exactly same size as mat-form-field like this:

[image]

but I don't know how to modify the width size and position of the dropdown container, do how can I modify that width size and position.

here is a small example with the component:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rllajkqybnmy

Comment: @WilliamHampshire edited question, is not about how I wrote my code but is about how the component is build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unfortunately, you need to add `!important` to the things you add since angular material adds the location as a `style` attribute

basically, you need to add\change 3 attributes:

- max-width - don't allow the select to change if content is wider
- min-width - same
- transform - to change the location of the select

notice that there's still an animation placement which starts at the original position.

This is the basic change:

```
.mat-select-panel {
  min-width: 180px !important;
  max-width: 180px !important;
  transform: translate(-2px, 44px) !important;
}

/* this will hide the element while it's being animated because
   the animation happens for the original position */

.mat-select-panel.ng-animating {
  display: none;
}
```

Add that to your `styles.css`, since this element is injected outside of the component.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-location?file=styles.css

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to fix the animation

Comment: added a solution to hide the animations for now

Comment: You can also try `@angular/flex-layout`

Comment: great, it works! just a clarification: if you use "display:none" on .ng-animating, the dropdown lost his position. It's better use "visibility: hidden;"

Comment: @HouseFragance that doesn't happen to me in the demo I attached. What exactly do you mean? What you said is true when using this with angular html attributes, but I don't think it's true when using regular css. The component still exists in the HTML and looks like angular adds the correct location

Comment: @thatkookooguy using margin instead of translate will fix the animation issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to fix [disableOptionCentering]="true"...

A hack I found to disable the animation:

```
// TS - Remove Mat-Select Dropdown animation (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857)
MatSelect['decorators'][0].args[0].animations[0] = trigger('transformPanel', []);

// CSS - Fix alignment
.mat-select-panel {
    margin: 21px 0 35px 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which keeps the animation:

```
// get hold of your mat-select
@ViewChild(MatSelect)
_mySelect: MatSelect;

// assign a custom panel class to the mat-select connected overlay
ngOnInit() {
  this._mySelect.overlayDir.panelClass = 'my-select-overlay';
}

// CSS (global or using ViewEncapsulation.none) - fix width with padding and/or max-width
.my-select-overlay {
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-width: 180px !important; //min-width needs important to override the element style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the position with margin instead of transform then the animation issue will be fixed!

Example instead of:

```
transform: translate(-2px, 44px) !important;
```

do

```
margin-top: 44px;
margin-left: -2px;
```

and that will remove the animation issue.